# Why is suhosin used?

Tags: php

I found php.ini inside my website directory . The directory structure is

> /mobiles/images/php.ini

Inisde the php.ini i noticed this line `suhosin.simulation On`

Why is this used and what does it do .

Comment: It's detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suhosin).

Comment: It should be noted that `suhosin.simulation On` means that Suhosin is actually effectively *disabled*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/

> Suhosin is an advanced protection system for PHP installations. It was
>   designed to protect servers and users from known and unknown flaws in
>   PHP applications and the PHP core. Suhosin comes in two independent
>   parts, that can be used separately or in combination. The first part
>   is a small patch against the PHP core, that implements a few low-level
>   protections against bufferoverflows or format string vulnerabilities
>   and the second part is a powerful PHP extension that implements all
>   the other protections

http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.simulation

> When Suhosin runs in simulation mode, violations are logged as usual,
>   but nothing is blocked or removed from the request.

Comment: what will happen if i remove that line from it. it will affect my website.

Comment: @RagavendranRamesh the default is 'off' so removing that line will switch off simulation.  This will only have an effect if you are experiencing violations - in which case, removing that line will block the action rather than simply reporting the violation.